# Why do we take different elemental thickness for calculation of volume and area of sphere?

Tags: calculus, area, volume, spheres

Why do we take thickness be differential of distance apart of elemental mass when calculating volume and be differential length of arc when calculating area of the sphere when integrating in terms of angle.

[image: sphere] [image: elemental part]

Before going into depth I refer [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546395/why-doesnt-this-method-work-for-getting-volume-of-a-sphere-and-how-to-find-vol) first.

So what I learnt is that when getting small volume we take
$$dl = d(R\sin θ) = R\cos θ\cdot dθ <<$$
$$r = R\cosθ$$
$$dV = πr^2\cdot dl$$

While when calculating area we take $dl$,
$$dθ = \frac{dl}{R}$$
$$dl = R\cdot dθ <<$$
$$dA = 2πr\cdot dl$$

But like why different elemental thickness ($dl$) for those calculations?

> If I wasn't able to make you understand what I said, then see the second figure, the $h$ is taken as $dl$ in calculation of volume while the *curved-surface* is used as $dl$ for calculation of area

**My Question is: *WHY***

Comment: What are these "<<" supposed to mean in the formulae?

Comment: Nothing, it was just for highlighting stuffs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of these computations as bases on the piling of *cone* frustra.

The volume of a single frustrum is the base area by the height, $\pi r^2\,dh$.

The lateral area is the circumference of the base times the *slant height*, $2\pi r\dfrac{dh}{\cos\theta}$.

(For thin frustra, the difference between the two bases does not matter.)

Comment: I am confused towards the volume calculation, why didn't we took the curved surface (slant height) ? If we take frustum's height, we are missing very small volumes, aren't we?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu: by analogy, when computing the area of a right trapezoid, will you take the height or the oblique side length ?

Comment: Ohh right, gotcha will take perpendicular height.

Answer (score 0):

This is because $\theta \to 0$ so
$$
\frac{d \sin \theta}{d\theta}=\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}=1
$$
In other words if $\theta$ is small the difference with $\sin \theta$ is much more small.

Comment: But question remains the same why do we take different elemental length for the elemental thickness?

Comment: Because for the surface we need an arc along the surface and for the volume the height of the disc.

Comment: why didn't we took the curved surface (slant height) in volume calculation? If we take height of disc, we are missing very small volumes or taking very small excess volume, aren't we?

Comment: My answer explain exactly why, for $\theta \to 0$ the curved arc and the height are ''the same'', so the the ''very small excess volume'' goes also to $0$

Comment: But if we take height of disc, https://i.imgur.com/zqo3ZsQ.jpg this much volume is excess right, but if you take slant height then check the post linked in the question it gives $\frac{π^2r^3}{2}$ as volume which is wrong right?